# Logo not appearing Cognito entries or printed form

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I print an entry with the company logo?

When I print or view the entries the logo does not appear at the top of the page like it used to.

June 9th I printed an entry and the logo and form name appeared on the printed copy, as of June 22 it no longer shows the logo or form name when viewing or printing entries.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

We just released the new Save to PDF feature. Using this feature you can save your form from the entries screen. You can include the logo at the top of your form when you save. Once saved you can print the saved PDF.